# Generate Python function in runtime and invoke them with string name

Tags: python, function, runtime

foo.py

```
def foo_001(para): tmp = para + 2 return tmp 
def foo_002(para): tmp = para * 2 return tmp 
def foo_003(para): tmp = para / 2 return tmp 

... 
def foo_100(para): tmp = #complex algo, return tmp
```

main.py

```
from foo import * 
fun_name = ["foo_001","foo_002","foo_002" ... "foo_100"] 

src = 1 
rzt = []  
for i in fun_name: 
    rzt.extent(eval(i)(src))
```

here is my question:

1. can I get the fun_name list in runtime, because I want save them in a text file?
2. I found there's common part in function defination which is "tmp = #algo", can I extract them out form those definations and can I define those functions in runtime? I want something like this:

foo.py

```
def foo_factory():  
    # in somehow 
    return adict      #function_name/function pair  

template = [ 
["foo_001","tmp = para + 2"], 
["foo_002","tmp = para * 2"], 
["foo_002","tmp = para + 2"], 
... 
["foo_100","tmp = #complex algo"]
```

main.py

```
from foo import * 
dic = foo_factory(template) 
fun_name = dic.keys() 
src = 1 
rzt = []  
for i in fun_name: 
    rzt.extent(eval(i)(src))  
        #or 
    rzt.extent(dic(i)())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fnmap = {
  'foo_001': foo_001,
  'foo_002': foo_002,
  'foo_003': foo_003,
}

print fnmap['foo_002'](3)
```

Use a decorator to enumerate the functions if you don't feel like typing out the whole map.

Comment: thanks for reply, but your answer and decorator may not  what I want,  i want a sinppet may generate the functions while function's name in runtime and it can conduct same action on next run.